# change orientation of secondary display

Tags: delphi

Anyone can change the orientation of secondary display using Delphi VCL tools?
Change the orientation of the primary display work fine.
If I try change the secondary display, either it will not work, or I will receive error messages:
System error 5 or faulty turn to DLL.
There is a C# example, but can't translate to Delphi. Can't find some features and records.
It seems that in Firemonkey there are corresponding options, but I need a solution in VCL.

Comment: There is nothing in the native VCL for this, so you are going to have to resort to using Win32 APIs directly. What have you tried so far that is not working for you? Please show your actual code. And what do the FMX and C# examples look like? Have you tried looking at FMX's/.NET's source code to see what they are doing under the hood that you might port to your Delphi code?

Comment: https://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/02/11/changing-screen-orientation-programmatically-using-delphi/ -- exaple for delphi

Comment: Perhaps mitecs Screen component can do this ... https://www.mitec.cz/msics.html (There is a Demo reading the Values ... i dont know if it can set values)